# When linking to a page with the id, is it possible to land partially down the page and not right at the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm only asking because the header is fixed to the top of the page and it has a height of 75px, so when I click on a link (`<a href="/company/#contact/">contact</a>`) it does got to that section but the top part sits behind the header. Is there anyway to link to the sections and have an offset of 75px above it?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have an absolutely positioned header, you need to add 75px top margin to your top-most element, or add another element above that which is blank and is 75px tall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution to what others have proposed would be overriding the browser's default behavior of scrolling to the anchors, and substitute that with your own way of calculating the scrolling based on the offset of the target element from the top, i.e. `.offset().top` and then subtracting the height of the fixed header element.

Let's say you have the following markup:

```
<header>
    Fixed header.
    <a href="#head1">Heading 1</a>
    <!-- more headers -->
</header>
<h1 id="head1">Heading 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vel dictum nulla. Pellentesque tincidun</p>
<!-- more content -->
```

For the JS, it is a bit tricky. First we determine whether the URL contains a hash, if yes, we call the function to reposition the page. Otherwise, we listen to click events triggered from all internal anchors, using the selector `a[href^="#"]`. For the function it has to perform this logic:

- Get the ID of the target element (inferred from `window.location.hash`, or the `href` attribute passed into it)
- Calculate the vertical offset of the target from the top of the page, done using `.offset().top`
- Manually scroll the viewport to the position, after taking into account the height of the fixed header (I will use `.height()`, to account for events where the header height might change or be dynamic — otherwise you can just use `75`).

Condensing the points above, we can use the following script:

```
$(function() {
    // Define scroll position modifier
    var scrollPos = function(targetID) {
        var targetOffset = $(targetID).offset().top;
        $(window).scrollTop(targetOffset - $('header').height());
    };

    // Update scroll position if hash is detected in URL
    if(window.location.hash) {
        // Use .substring(1) to remove '#' at the front
        scrollPos(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    }

    // Update scroll position when navigated
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
        // Prevent native scrolling
        e.preventDefault();

        // Manual scroll position update
        scrollPos($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/u11011jc/

Comment: Will this work if I'm navigating from one page to another? The links are in a footer. I don't like it this way but it's the way the owner wants it.

Comment: I've already covered that part in my answer ("First we determine whether the URL contains a hash"), by checking for the presence of hash in the URL, i.e. `window.location.hash`

Comment: Ok Thanks! initially when I added the code it funked up some styles in the footer, going to poke around at it to see if I can get it working

Comment: The CSS in my fiddle is only for visual demo, you don't actually need to use it at all.

Comment: I didn't, I think it was conflicting with other jQuery on the page. I moved it around and it now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: "75px"
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8q9xrzs0/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it scrolls up to the top of the page after navigating. I changed the html, body to an 'a' but it didn't respond at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an absolutely positioned (or fixed position) header, you need to have some compensation to bring your entire body content down.

You should add a section above your top-most section on your page and give it a height of 75px.  This will think the page is 75px lower than it actually is.  (I usually call this `nav-push`, like it's pushing the content down because of the nav)

Another solution is to give your anchor tag a class and position it relatively, then give it a top offset of 75px

```
a#contact {
    position:relative;
    top:-75px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked initially, until I scrolled up. It makes some of the content on the page overlap. I'm going to try to get it to work :D

Comment: @user2596635 You may have to use `position:absolute;` on the anchor, while the container has `position:relative;`.  If your anchors are styled, then this could cause a headache.  Try to keep your anchors unstyled and hidden.